# Django - cannot make url with variable in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I want to have a button which links to page *make-appointment*

**template.html**

```
{% for key, value in closest_free_spots.items %}
...
<a href="{% url 'make-appointment' value.pk %}"><button type="button">{{ value.datetime }}</button></a>
```

**urls.py**

```py
    url(r'^umowienie-spotkania/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TestPy.views.MakingAppointmentView.as_view(),
            name='make-appointment'),
```

However when I try to launch it, I get error:

```
Reverse for 'make-appointment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['umowienie-spotkania/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

It looks like the value.pk is not correct, but when I print it one line above, it gives correct value (i.e. 4).

What is the problem? What I'm missing?

**closest_free_spots definition** - value is object from *CalendarFreeSlot* model

```py
    closest_free_spots = {
        lawyer: TestPy.models.CalendarFreeSlot.objects.filter(Q(lawyer_id=lawyer) & Q(is_available=True)).first() for
        lawyer in object_list}
```

**models.py**

```py
class CalendarFreeSlot(models.Model):
    lawyer_id = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `closest_free_spots` dict comprehension uses `CalendarFreeSlot.objects.filter(...).first()`, which can return `None`. This leads to the `with arguments '('',)'` part of the error message.

Checking `{{ value.pk }}` in the template was a good idea, but it looks like you missed that there isn't a value for every item in the dictionary.

You could handle this by checking `{% if value %}` in the template.

```
{% for key, value in closest_free_spots.items %}
{% if value %}
<a href="{% url 'make-appointment' value.pk %}"><button type="button">{{ value.datetime }}</button></a>
{% else %}
{{ key }} has not free spots
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```